# Convert string to datetime in python and compare to current time

Tags: python, datetime, date

I'm trying to convert a string in the format:

```
Apr 18 17:19:42
```

to datetime so that I can compare the current time with that time and see if they are off by a minute.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As S1R has already pointed out, the [`strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) method is what you want. You'll also need to specify the year, since its not included in your date string:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> s = "Apr 18 17:19:42"
>>> t = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%b %d %H:%M:%S")
>>> t
datetime.datetime(1900, 4, 18, 17, 19, 42)
>>> t = t.replace(year = 2012)
>>> n = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> n
datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 20, 10, 21, 42, 165657)
>>> d = n-t
>>> d.total_seconds()
147720.165657
```

Answer (score 3):

[`strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime) is what you need, it is used to change a string to a datetime

So in your case it would be;

```
from datetime import datetime
todaysdate = datetime.strptime('Apr 18 17:19:42', '%b %d %H:%M:%S')
```